# Save Struct to binary file

Tags: go

I'm trying same my nested struct to binary files.
In future there will be a lots of "Rooms" records so serialized struct in binary file is the best approach I think.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "log"
    "time"
)

type House struct {
    ID     int
    Floors int
    Rooms  []Room
}

type Room struct {
    Width       int
    Height      int
    Description string
    CreatedAt   time.Time
}

func main() {
    var house House = House{
        ID: 1,
        Floors: 3,
    }

    house.Rooms = append(house.Rooms, Room{Width: 20, Height: 30, CreatedAt: time.Now(), Description: "This is description"})
    house.Rooms = append(house.Rooms, Room{Width: 14, Height: 21, CreatedAt: time.Now(), Description: "This is other description"})
    house.Rooms = append(house.Rooms, Room{Width: 12, Height: 43, CreatedAt: time.Now(), Description: "This is other desc"})

    log.Println(house)

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err := binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, house)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

}
```

But I have error:
- Binary.Write: invalid type main.House

Could someone help me because I cant find solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `binary.Write` documentation:

> Data must be a fixed-size value or a slice of fixed-size values, or a pointer to such data.

Your `House` structure is not a fixed size value.

You might consider writing/reading `House` and `Room` separately. The `House` you use to store house structs must not contain a slice, so you can declare another `House` struct that you use to read/write from your file.

Instead of a binary file you can store your objects as JSON, and then you wouldn't need to deal with this problem.